# Проблемы с кодировкой Python

Tags: python, кодировка, перекодировка

Как распознать данные кракозябры?:

```
Ğ£ Ğ²Ğ°Ñ� ĞµÑ�Ñ‚ÑŒ ĞµÑ‰Ğµ Ğ´Ğ¾Ğ¿Ğ¾Ğ»Ğ½Ğ¸Ñ‚ĞµĞ»ÑŒĞ½Ñ‹Ğµ Ğ²Ğ¾Ğ¿Ñ€Ğ¾Ñ�Ñ‹?
```

```
Str = "Ğ£ Ğ²Ğ°Ñ� ĞµÑ�Ñ‚ÑŒ ĞµÑ‰Ğµ Ğ´Ğ¾Ğ¿Ğ¾Ğ»Ğ½Ğ¸Ñ‚ĞµĞ»ÑŒĞ½Ñ‹Ğµ Ğ²Ğ¾Ğ¿Ñ€Ğ¾Ñ�Ñ‹?"

Str = Str.encode('utf8')
print(Str)
Str = Str.decode('utf8')
print(Str)
Str = Str.encode('cp1254').decode('utf8')
print(Str)
```

Результат:

```
b'\xc4\x9e\xc2\xa3 \xc4\x9e\xc2\xb2\xc4\x9e\xc2\xb0\xc3\x91\xef\xbf\xbd \xc4\x9e\xc2\xb5\xc3\x91\xef\xbf\xbd\xc3\x91\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x91\xc5\x92 \xc4\x9e\xc2\xb5\xc3\x91\xe2\x80\xb0\xc4\x9e\xc2\xb5 \xc4\x9e\xc2\xb4\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbe\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbf\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbe\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbb\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbd\xc4\x9e\xc2\xb8\xc3\x91\xe2\x80\x9a\xc4\x9e\xc2\xb5\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbb\xc3\x91\xc5\x92\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbd\xc3\x91\xe2\x80\xb9\xc4\x9e\xc2\xb5 \xc4\x9e\xc2\xb2\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbe\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbf\xc3\x91\xe2\x82\xac\xc4\x9e\xc2\xbe\xc3\x91\xef\xbf\xbd\xc3\x91\xe2\x80\xb9?'
Ğ£ Ğ²Ğ°Ñ� ĞµÑ�Ñ‚ÑŒ ĞµÑ‰Ğµ Ğ´Ğ¾Ğ¿Ğ¾Ğ»Ğ½Ğ¸Ñ‚ĞµĞ»ÑŒĞ½Ñ‹Ğµ Ğ²Ğ¾Ğ¿Ñ€Ğ¾Ñ�Ñ‹?
Traceback (most recent call last):

    Str = Str.encode('cp1254').decode('utf8')

    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 8: character maps to <undefined>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: это точно текст?

Comment: `s.encode('cp1254', errors='replace').decode('utf-8', errors='replace')`

Comment: Это не то cp1251, не то utf8, конвертированный с какого-то перепугу в cp1254. Точнее сказать нельзя, ибо текст необратимо повреждён. Текст декодируется в *У ва� е� ть еще дополнительные вопро� ы?*